# How to perform subquery in FROM clause with Yii 1.1?

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii1.x

I have a fairly large and complex query being generated by Yii. To generate this query we're utilizing `CDbCritera::with` to eagerly load multiple related models, and we're using multiple scopes to limit the records returned. The query being generated is roughly 700 lines long, but looks something like this:

```
SELECT `t`.`column1` as `t0_c0`,
       `t`.`column2` as `t0_c1`,
       `related1`.`column1` as `t1_c0`,
       ...
       `related9`.`column5` as `t9_c4`
FROM `model` `t`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `other_model` `related1`
                 ON ( `t`.`other_model_id` = `related1`.`id` )
    ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `more_models` `related9`
                 ON ( `t`.`more_models_id` = `related9`.`id` )
WHERE
    ...big long WHERE clause using all of related1 - related9 to filter model...
LIMIT 10
```

Our database has a not insignificant amount of data, but not obscene, either. In this case the `model` table has about 126000 rows, every "related" model is a `BELONGS_TO` relationship and there is an index on `t.XXX_id` so the join is fairly trivial. The problem is the complexity of the WHERE clause, possessing multiple `COALESCE` and `IF` and `CASE` clauses. Performing the filter on our 126000 rows is taking 2.6 seconds -- far longer than we would like for an API endpoint.

The WHERE clause is divided into multiple different sections like so:

```
WHERE
    ( ... part 1 ... )
    AND
    ( ... part 2 ... )
    AND
    ( ... part 3 ... )
```

With each part corresponding to one of the scopes, and each part using one or more related models

One of the scopes filters on only a ***single*** related model, and in doing so filters our table down from 126000 rows to about 2000 rows. I found experimentally (in MySQL Workbench) that I could get our query from 2.6 seconds to 0.2 seconds by simply doing this:

```
SELECT `t`.`column1` as `t0_c0`,
       `t`.`column2` as `t0_c1`,
       `related1`.`column1` as `t1_c0`,
       ...
       `related9`.`column5` as `t9_c4`
FROM
    (
        SELECT `model`.*
        FROM `model`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `other_model`
                     ON ( `t`.`other_model_id` = `other_model`.`id` )
        WHERE
            ( ... part 1 ... )
    ) `t`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `other_model` `related1`
                 ON ( `t`.`other_model_id` = `related1`.`id` )
    ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `more_models` `related9`
                 ON ( `t`.`more_models_id` = `related9`.`id` )
WHERE
    ( ... part 2 ... )
    AND
    ( ... part 3 ... )
LIMIT 10
```

This way instead of performing the very complex `WHERE` clause on all 126000 rows of the original `model` table, we perform the much simpler (and index-enhanced) `WHERE` clause on these 126000 rows and then perform the complex `WHERE` clause on only the 2000 relevant rows. The results of the two queries are identical, but using a subquery in the `FROM` clause causes it to run 13x faster.

The problem is, I have no idea how to do this in Yii. I know that I can use `CDbCommand` to build a query and even pass in raw SQL, but what I'll get back is an array of "rows" -- they won't be understood by Yii and properly converted to the right models.

Does Yii's ActiveRecord system have a way to say something like the following?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->scopes = array("part1");
$subQuery = Model::model()->buildQuery($criteria);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->scopes = array("part2", "part3");
$fullQuery = $subQuery->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a perfect solution, I did find something that's ***almost*** as good. Break the original query into two:

1. Get the IDs or models you wish to select in the FROM subquery
2. Append a WHERE to the outer query with `id in (...)`

If anyone is interested I'll hunt down the code I wrote for this to post in the answer as an example, but so far this question has gotten very little attention and once I found a pseudo-decent solution I've moved on.